# Sqlite query to get next avaiable character of search text which contains in firstname or lastname

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How to query sqlite database to get list of next available characters after the search keyword in two columns. for example, if the search keyword is ’and’
and let the columns be firstname and lastname :

```
And[y] Xyz
And[r]ew And[z]
Xyz And[o]n
Mirand[a] Lorand[e]
```

then i should get the characters [y,r,z,o,a,e].

I tried with substr and instr, but i couldn't write a query that looks in both first and last name and return next character in  both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `UNION ALL` for the values from the 2 columns and by using rowid to get the correct order:

```
select nextchar from (
  select
    1 col, 
    rowid,
    substr(firstname, instr(lower(firstname), 'and') + 3, 1) nextchar
  from names 
  where firstname like '%and%'
  union all 
  select
    2, 
    rowid,
    substr(lastname, instr(lower(lastname), 'and') + 3, 1)
  from names 
  where lastname like '%and%'
) t
order by t.rowid, t.col
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8raUjQ9gF9UcK7GKSkv6Bg/0).
Results:

```
| nextchar |
| -------- |
| y        |
| r        |
| z        |
| o        |
| a        |
| e        |
```

If you want the result as a comma separated string, use `group_concat()`:

```
select group_concat(nextchar) chars from (
  select nextchar from (
    select
      1 col, 
      rowid,
      substr(firstname, instr(lower(firstname), 'and') + 3, 1) nextchar
    from names 
    where firstname like '%and%'
    union all 
    select
      2, 
      rowid,
      substr(lastname, instr(lower(lastname), 'and') + 3, 1)
    from names 
    where lastname like '%and%'
  ) t
  order by t.rowid, t.col
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8raUjQ9gF9UcK7GKSkv6Bg/1).
Result:

```
| chars       |
| ----------- |
| y,r,z,o,a,e |
```

Comment: what will be rowid?

Comment: In SQLite every row has a numeric id, this is `rowid`. I use this to preserve the order of the rows. Find more here: https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html